# Adding Input control to the pages with jQuery has problem with HttpFileCollection in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, html, vb.net

I'm trying to add upload controls to the page.

This HTML mark-up with JavaScript is working fine but there
s no option to remove the added control:

**1. Example A**

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Multi File Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p id="upload-area">
    </p>
    <input id="AddFile" type="button" value="Add file" onclick="addFileUploadBox()" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    <p>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Upload Now" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" /></p>
    <span id="Span1" runat="server" />

    <script type="text/javascript">


        function addFileUploadBox() {
            if (!document.getElementById || !document.createElement)
                return false;

            var uploadArea = document.getElementById("upload-area");

            if (!uploadArea)
                return;

            var newLine = document.createElement("br");
            uploadArea.appendChild(newLine);

            var newUploadBox = document.createElement("input");

            // Set up the new input for file uploads
            newUploadBox.type = "file";
            newUploadBox.size = "60";

            // The new box needs a name and an ID
            if (!addFileUploadBox.lastAssignedId)
                addFileUploadBox.lastAssignedId = 100;

            newUploadBox.setAttribute("id", "dynamic" + addFileUploadBox.lastAssignedId);
            newUploadBox.setAttribute("name", "dynamic:" + addFileUploadBox.lastAssignedId);
            uploadArea.appendChild(newUploadBox);
            addFileUploadBox.lastAssignedId++;
        }
    </script>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**1. Example A : the code behind**

```
     Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
            Dim uploads As HttpFileCollection
            uploads = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files

            Dim sfile As String


            For i As Integer = 0 To (uploads.Count - 1)

                If (uploads(i).ContentLength > 0) Then
                    Dim c As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uploads(i).FileName)

                    Try
                        uploads(i).SaveAs("C:\UploadedUserFiles\" + c)

                        sfile += uploads(i).FileName & "<br/>"


                        Span1.InnerHtml = "File Uploaded Sucessfully."
                    Catch Exp As Exception
                        Span1.InnerHtml = "Some Error occured."
                    End Try

                End If

            Next i

            Label1.Text = sfile


        End Sub
```

**2. Example B with jQuery and option to "Remove" added control**
    However when I changed JavaScript to jQuery, it doesn't work. I can add and remove control but when I submit no files are uploaded.  Mark-up with jQuery:

```
    <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="add-remove-control.aspx.vb"
        Inherits="APIU.Web.add_remove_control" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>

        <script src="_Assets/scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {

                var i = 1;
                //allow only 3 elements

                $('#add').click(function() {
                    if (i < 4) {
                        var add_input = '<input type="file" id="' + 'dynamic:' + i + '" name="' + 'dynamic:' + i + '" />
                        var add_link = '<a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>'
                        $('body').append('<p>' + add_input + add_link + '</p>');
                        i++;
                    }
                });

                $('.remove').live('click', function() {
                    $(this).parent('p').remove();
                    i--;
                });


            });
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <a href="#" id="add">Add</a>
            <input id="File1" type="file" runat="server" size="60" />
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
            <br />
            <p>
                &nbsp;</p>
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**2. Example B: the code behind:**

```
    Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim uploads As HttpFileCollection
        uploads = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files

        Dim sfile As String


        For i As Integer = 0 To (uploads.Count - 1)

            If (uploads(i).ContentLength > 0) Then
                Dim c As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uploads(i).FileName)

                Try
                    uploads(i).SaveAs("C:\UploadedUserFiles\" + c)

                    sfile += uploads(i).FileName & "<br/>"

                Catch Exp As Exception

                End Try

            End If

        Next i


    End Sub
```

Every thing was working fine with Example A, only there's no option to remove the added contorls.When I added "Remove" control option with jQuery in Example B, HttpFileCollection can't get any file from input control added to the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Example A, in the form tag has enctype="multipart/form-data">

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

but there's no enctype property in Example B,

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
```

Here's a reference on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlform.enctype.aspx) and a question about enctype property on [asp.net forum](http://forums.asp.net/t/1257093.aspx).

If you need to only set form property of enctype to a specific page only, in case you are using master page, you can set property to that page like this:

```
If Not Page.IsPostBack() Then

    Me.Form.Enctype = "multipart/form-data"

End If
```

Cheer. :D

Comment: Thank you for the references.